About Geomesa fs integration with geoserver
I am facing issue while creating store for geomesa fs .My Store gets created but no layers are visible to publish for that storage.
what are the issues you think for that.
if anyone already perfom this type of step up .please suggest me steps.

what does the log file say?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi Satarkar, have you completed the GeoMesa FSDS tutorial here: https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-fsds.html ?
That would walk you through the steps necessary to see data in GeoServer from the GeoMesa FileSytem data store.
